# Console Automatic Prefix?

Tags: c#, console

I just started with C# and want to test myself by trying to make a simple chatbot.

Is it possible to make it so that when the user inputs a text or the chatbot outputs a text it aways has something before it? like:

```
-->You: "Hi"
-->Bot: "Hello"
```

So it has the `-->` always at the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the functionality in a method:

```
public void BotResponse(string response) {
    Console.WriteLine("---> " + response);
}
```

Then every time the bot responds.. call the method instead:

```
BotResponse("Hello User!");
// will output: ---> Hello User!
```

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what I wanted

Comment: @jonathanh8686 You can also create one for the user before they input something using `Console.Write()`